# IDA C++ SDK: Getting bytes/opcodes in coordination to the address

Tags: c++, sdk, ida

[image: Example]

For example, I want to be able to get 0x8B from providing the address 0x6B8B88.

How is this possible with the IDA SDK in C++. I was only able to find methods for idapython (which I DO NOT need).

Comment: It is recommended to ask questions about Reverse Engineering in [Reverse Engineering Stack Exchange](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it.

The function is called: get_byte

example:

```
get_byte(0xD33DB3AF);
```